# how can i do select options required & Email validation in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when clicked on submit button, it will call function, in that function i am trying to write logic to disable submit button when fields are not valid, here email must be contain @, dot and after dot minimum 2 & maximum 4 alphabet characters. I tried bellow code.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <form name="myForm">
            <div>
                <select id="country" style="width:250px;" class="" name="selectFranchise" ng-model="state1" ng-change="displayState(state1)"
                    ng-required>
                    <option ng-repeat="(key,country) in countries"  value="{{key}}">{{country[0]}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select id="state" ng-disabled="!states[state1].length" ng-model="cities" ng-required>
                    <option ng-repeat="(state,city) in states[state1]" value="{{city}}">{{city}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type="email" ng-disable="myForm.user.email.$valid" ng-model="user.email" name="eamil" ng-required/>
            <button ng-disable="myForm.user.email.$valid" ng-click="formsubmit();">submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.formsubmit = function () {

        }
        $scope.states = {
            "IN": [
                "Delhi",
                "Goa",
                "Gujarat",
                "Himachal Pradesh",
            ]
        };
        $scope.countries = {
            IN: ["India"],
            ZA: ["South Africa"],
            AT: ["Austria"]
        }
        $scope.state1 = Object.keys($scope.countries)[0];
        $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    });
```

### [***jsfiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc3n55d2/19/)

Comment: Where is your logic for validating email? Have you tried anything?

Comment: now i edit html and added ng-disabled,  here how write logic in function using angualr js, can you help me

Comment: if your fields are not valid then on click of Submit button, the button will get disabled. Then if the fields become valid, then how are you going to handle the disabled Submit button?

Comment: yes your right, then how i can do 'dot after dot minimum 2 & maximum 4 alphabet characters'

Comment: der are two options
1> on blur, in this case, you can play with the Submit buttons' state and fire the respective validations.
2> on submit, in this case, let submit button be enabled but it should be processed only when form is valid.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form role="form" name="signupForm" ng-submit="signup()" novalidate>

  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                      <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
                      <div class="inputGroup">
                        <input type="text" id="su_username" name="username" class="form-control input-md"
                               ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="8" required>
                        <span class="inputBar"></span>
                        <label translate="signup.form.username">Username</label>
                        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="signupForm.username.$dirty && signupForm.username.$invalid">
                          <span ng-show="signupForm.username.$error.required" translate="signup.messages.validate.username.required">Username is required.</span>
                          <span ng-show="signupForm.username.$error.minlength" translate="signup.messages.validate.username.minlength">Username must be at least 8 characters.</span>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                      <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
                      <div class="inputGroup">
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="su_email" class="form-control input-md"
                               ng-model="user.email" required>
                        <span class="inputBar"></span>
                        <label translate="signup.form.email">Email Address</label>
                        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="signupForm.email.$dirty && signupForm.email.$invalid">
                          <span ng-show="signupForm.email.$error.required" translate="signup.messages.validate.email.required">Email is required.</span>
                          <span ng-show="signupForm.email.$error.email" translate="signup.messages.validate.email.invalid">Invalid email address.</span>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>



                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg btn-block" 
                              ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid ">
```

**1st** of all you need to give your form a name  here its `signupForm` .

**2nd** from there you need to give your input fields names  for example  here they are`username` and `email`.

**Then** you can use various angular  validation `directives` to set `validation` constrains  like `require` , `length` then you can check for validation error using  `signupForm.username.$invalid` and check various error  like `signupForm.email.$error.email`.

**Finally** if you want to check if the whole from is valid  use  `signupForm.$invalid`

and for number validation use

```
angular.module('test')
  .directive('validNumber', function() {
    return {
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        if(!ngModelCtrl) {
          return;
        }

        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
          if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
            val = '';
          }
          var clean = val.replace( /[^0-9\.]/g, '');
          if (val !== clean) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
            ngModelCtrl.$render();
          }
          return clean;
        });

        element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
          if(event.keyCode === 32) {
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

you can find github example  from [here](https://github.com/noman57/login)

Comment: length will user to setting min and max digits/ characters , here  only min 2 and 4 max characters not digistes

Comment: ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid || dataLoading ", here 'dataLoading' is a function or what is this why ?

Comment: ignore that .. i have  updated the code ... and for digits you can use custom validators

Comment: I have updated the answer with validnuber directive ..  or you can use pattern as well .. mark the answer as accepted if this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable the submit button, you can do something like this:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input ...>

  ...

  <button type="button" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="formsubmit();">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Notice that I have put `ng-disabled` with a condition of `myForm` being invalid. So, *instead of waiting for user to click the button, we are disabling the submit button upfront when form is invalid!*

For Email validation, I would suggest you to go with `<input type = "email"...>` unless you have specific email validation requirements not handled by `type = "email"`

Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc3n55d2/20/) which disables the submit button until we put a valid email address.

**Edit**: Here's an example of how `ng-pattern` can be used to validate email for given rules (i.e. email must contain @, dot and after dot minimum 2 & maximum 4 alphabet characters)

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="user.email" name="email" required
        ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/"/>
```

Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc3n55d2/21/)

Also, [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/k3cEzc/2/) for the email validation regex

Comment: here button is showing before 'dot' and after dot minimum 2 & maximum 4 alphabet characters. how can write logic for this to disable submit button

Comment: @sitabane use ng-pattern if you are using input type ='text' or else if you use input type="email" it will automatically validate email address for you and set field invalid like in my answer

Comment: ng-pattern=""?email must be contain @, dot and after dot minimum 2 & maximum 4 alphabet characters

Comment: @sitabane updated answer with `ng-pattern` example and fiddle that matches your email criteria (email must be contain @, dot and after dot minimum 2 & maximum 4 alphabet characters)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('jsbin', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function() {

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular JS</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="jsbin">
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as demo">
    <form name="form" novalidate ng-submit="validate()">
      <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required />
      <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.required">Required</span>
      <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.email">Invalid email</span>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-disabled="submitted && form.email.$error.required || submitted && form.email.$error.email" ng-click="submitted=true">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Check This Out.